# How to set up auto-deploy to AppEngine when pushing to Git Repository

Tags: python, git, google-app-engine, python-2.7, bitbucket

I've heard that other platforms support auto-deployment of their code to production when they push changes to their Git repository.

Can I set up something similar to this for AppEngine? How?

I'm using Python2.7 on Windows, and bitbucket as a repository.

Thanks!

Comment: Push to deploy was discontinued.
See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828257/push-to-deploy-pipelines-google-app-engine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since app engine deploy is just a python script, why can't you just write a shell script that calls 'git push' followed by 'python appcfg.py deploy'?

Any bitbucket hooks that will send from bitbucket->appengine after you upload to app is probably a bad idea since it will require storing your app engine login credentials on github.

Other projects might have your app server pull from github/bitbucket.  You can do this if your app engine site just serves static websites using http://drydrop.binaryage.com/, but you can't update actual running code this way.

Comment: Note : you can cache python code and import modules (python code) from a remote site and reload them with an import hook, but you cannot do it with http://drydrop.binaryage.com/

Answer (score 2):

Recently, App Engine added Push to Deploy features: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/push-to-deploy

It only has built in support for GitHub, but it might still be possible to configure BitBucket to work with it.

Comment: No, I didn't put much effort into BitBucket.

Comment: This article says it should work: http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/using-bitbucket-for-push-to-deploy.html

Comment: 404 on that page and this one is just empty! https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2014/04/using-github-for-push-to-deploy.html What's up Google?