# How to build and deploy my code using Google Cloud Shell

Tags: java, git, maven, google-app-engine

I have a Java project that I would like to deploy on Google App Engine. This is not my first time with Google App Engine so I know what dependencies/modifications I have to add to the pom.xml to make it work.

I have pushed the code to the Git hosting offered by Google Cloud(under the same project as the App Engine instance).

What I would like to do is go to google.cloud.com, sign in, enter console, enter shell and then write something to get the code, build it(mvn package locally), deploy it(google appengine:deploy locally) and be done with it.

Is there any way to do this? I have seen people refer to this method in forums but I haven't seen a proper example of how it could be done. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the details about `mvn` and other java-specific stuff, but for the general use of the cloud shell to do development of a GAE app stored in the Cloud Source Repositories check https://stackoverflow.com/a/42123320/4495081.

There really is not much of a difference between developing & deploying from your own local machine respository and doing it from the cloud shell.

One note though: the deployment is **not** `local` (as your `deploy it(google appengine:deploy locally)` mention may appear to suggest) - it is just as remote as it is when deploying from your laptop.

Comment: Thanks, that made sense. I expressed my self incorrectly, I meant deploying from local machine. Doesn't seem to be that big of a difference, only that I could skip a few steps in the online shell.