# App directory doesn't show up on google cloud shell

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Probably a stupid question.

I'm new to google app engine. So I followed the tutorial and successfully deployed their HelloWorld app, where the final steps are done on the cloud shell.

Then I built my own app in flask on my local machine, tested it (pushed the repo to the project's cloud repo) and deployed it from the command line (`gcloud app deploy`) and it works fine, anyone can use the app on their browser and I can also see the source code in the console website.

But I don't see any directories when I use the cloud shell. I get the prompt `username@project-id:~$` but when I `ls`, there's just one README file and no other directories, therefore I can't use the `devapp_sever.py`, `gcloud app deploy` or any other shell function on this project.

But when I choose the hello world project that was created initially, the shell shows an `src` directory which contains the app's code and I can use the shell and deploy the app from there.

What's happening here and what am I supposed to do.?

Answer (score 1):

Think of your Cloud Shell as just another workstation with local disk similar to your local machine. To deploy code to an app engine app, Google will create a Cloud Source Repository. Having said that, this is not related to your Cloud Shell. You can of course `git clone` any Git repo into your Cloud Shell.

Dan also wrote a nice explanation here -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42123320/7947020

Hope this clarifies it!

Comment: I read the article and my question is still not answered. According to the answer you referenced: " In the web-cached article all the ops are done inside the cloud shell, basically a local repo exists in your cloud shell "homedir". From there it is saved/uploaded to the cloud source repository:" But on my cloud shell I don't see any files. There's only one README file and no other directory.

Comment: It's only there if you specifically checked it out in your Cloud Shell. As I mentioned, think of it as the equivalent of your workstation under your desk. No repo is magically appearing in your home directory unless you specifically put it there.