# Google App Engine check update

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a way to check if there are updated files from the server using Google App Engine? Then download only the updated files to your local to match it on the server?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community -Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible if you're talking about the standard environment and you always follow disciplined app deployment procedure:

- deploy from a git repository (unsure if other VCS systems work)
- don't deploy when you have uncommitted changes in the repository from which you deploy

If you meet these requirements then you can access the source code for a particular deployed version of a service via StackDriver, as described in [Google Cloud DataStore automatic indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498821/google-cloud-datastore-automatic-indexing/47499884#47499884).

At least in my case in between the files in the root directory I found an automatically generated file called `source-context.json`, containing the git URL and revisionID of the repository from which the deployment was made. Which you can use to selectively update your local repo.

Another approach, requiring the same deployment discipline mentioned above, plus always deploying from the same repository, which you'll consider the unique master copy of your code or one of its mirrors (needed due to git's distributed nature). Then you only need to compare your local repo against the version being deployed in this master copy repo (or its mirror).

You *might* want to check out the [Google Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/) as a possible such master copy repo. Or mirroring a public repo master copy (see  [Connecting a Hosted Repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/connecting-hosted-repositories)). The advantage would be some convenience and integration with other Google Cloud Platform tools, for example:

- [`gcloud source repos`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/source/repos/)
- the [Source Browser](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/using-source-browser)
- deployments from the cloud shell, see for example [Google Cloud: How to deploy mirrored Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122249/google-cloud-how-to-deploy-mirrored-repository/42123320#42123320)

Otherwise direct downloading of the app code from GAE is monolithic - you can't select just specific files, see [Downloading Your Source Code](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-source-code).